# Reading Registry on IIS server with PHP com object not working

Tags: php, iis, com-object

I am trying to read a registry value on iis using the following script.

```
$shell = new COM("WScript.Shell") or die("Requires Windows Scripting Host");
$devenvpath=$shell->RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\App\\Pathsfirefox.exe");
```

It doesn't work.  It keeps telling me "Unable to open registry key".  I am assuming this is a permissions issue but not sure.  How can I get this to work.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got this working.  I had to add the php extension for php_com_dotnet.dll.  I did this inside php manager in IIS manager.  Hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps its only a typo on your original post, but it looks to me as though there ought to be a "\" between "Paths" and "Firefox.exe" in that registry line.

```
$devenvpath=$shell->RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\App\\Paths\\firefox.exe");
```

Comment: Nope still not working.  It dies at the $shell line.  I never get the echo statment below it to work
    try {
    $shell = new COM("WScript.Shell") or die("Requires Windows Scripting Host");
    echo "Never gets past the line above";
    $response = $shell->RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\App Paths\\firefox.exe\\Path");
    var_dump( $response );
    } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }